# PyBrain - how to validate my trained network against a test data?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, pybrain

So I have a ClassificationDataSet in PyBrain which I have trained with the appropriate data. Namely, the input is the following:

```
trainSet.addSample([0,0,0,0],[1])
trainSet.addSample([0,0,0,1],[0])
trainSet.addSample([0,0,1,0],[0])
trainSet.addSample([0,0,1,1],[1])
trainSet.addSample([0,1,0,0],[0])
trainSet.addSample([0,1,0,1],[1])
trainSet.addSample([0,1,1,0],[1])
trainSet.addSample([0,1,1,1],[0])
trainSet.addSample([1,0,0,0],[0])
trainSet.addSample([1,0,0,1],[1])
```

The pattern is simple. If there is an even number of 1's then the output should be 1, otherwise it is 0. I want to run the following inputs:

```
[1,0,0,1],[1]
[1,1,0,1],[0]
[1,0,1,1],[0]
[1,0,1,0],[1]
```

And see whether the neural network will recognise the pattern. As said previously, I've already trained the network. How do I validate it against the inputs above?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You first have to [create a network](http://pybrain.org/docs/quickstart/network.html#the-buildnetwork-shortcut) and [train it on your dataset](http://pybrain.org/docs/quickstart/training.html).

Then you have to use [`activate`](http://pybrain.org/docs/tutorial/netmodcon.html#examining-a-network) to get a result from your inputs and test if it matches the desired output.

One easy way to do it is:

```
testOutput = { [1,0,0,1] : [1], [1,1,0,1] : [0], [1,0,1,1]:[0], [1,0,1,0]:[1] }

for input, expectedOutput in testInput.items():
    output = net.activate(input)
    if output != expectedOutput:
        print "{} didn't match the desired output." 
        print "Expected {}, got {}".format(input, expectedOutput, output)
```

Comment: What does .activate() return? I keep getting floats and it is confusing me.. Care to explain?

Comment: Added a link to the documentation (on activate) ; I'm not a PyBrain user, currently installing the package to do a minimal test of this method.

Comment: Oops. I had mistaken your dataset for a network. Added some links to clarify things.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your effort!!! I have already created a network and a dataset and trained the net using the dataset.. However.. I keep getting funny results.. Like [[ 0.        ]
 [ 0.64476526]
 [ 0.54229964]
 [ 0.3103782 ]] after i call activate on those values.. can you tell me what those value mean??

Comment: The values returned depends on the kind of networks you used. I guess some networks do some kind of interpolation between the inputs given in the dataset. (and may not return the exact data you've given them)